# Function to change the value after some time. Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vue-props

I want to change the value of a boolean after some time and keep repeating the process. Then I want to pass the value to a child component individually. Here **changeActive()** is the function to change the value of the **active** boolean. I want to change the value to the first prop then after some time second prop and so on.

```
<template>
<div style="width:300px; margin: auto;">
      <RatingLabel 
      :rating='rating[0]'
      :active='active'
      style="margin: auto;"
      />
      <RatingLabel 
      :rating='rating[1]'
      :active='active'
      style="float: right;"
      />
      <RatingLabel 
      :rating='rating[2]'
      :active='active'
      />
      <RatingLabel 
      :rating='rating[3]'
      :active='active'
      style="margin: auto;"
      />
</div>
</template>

<script>
import RatingLabel from '../atomic/RatingLabel'
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
export default {
      components: {
            RatingLabel,
      },

      data() {
            return {
                  active: false,
            }
      },

      methods: {
            changeActive() {
                  setTimeout(function(){ 
                        this.active = !this.active;
                        console.log(this.active)
                   }, 3000);
            }
      },

      mounted() {
            this.changeActive()
      },

      computed: mapState(['rating'])
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you need to do:

1. Instead of repeating the component, add a `v-for` to it:

```
<RatingLabel v-for="(rating,i) in ratings" :key="i" :rating="rating"/>
```

2. Since each prop is seperate, you need to make `active` a list and pass each element as a prop according to the index as follows:

Add this to `data` instead

```
activeList: [],
```

So the component rendering would be:

```
<RatingLabel v-for="(rating,i) in ratings" :key="i" :active="activeList[i] || false" :rating="rating"/>
```

3. Since you need to set each `prop` to true every period of time, you need `setInterval` function:

Add this to `data`:

```
time:''
```

And then use it as the interval:

```
mounted() {
    this.changeActive();
},
methods: {
     changeActive: function() {
          let count = 0;
          var x = setInterval(() => {      
               this.activeList.push(true);
               count++;
               if (count == this.ratings.length) clearInterval(x);  
          }, 3000);        
     },
},
```